# python wix multithreading connectionerror

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, python-requests

Okay so I've tried to find the answers myself. I think I know how to solve it, I just don't know how to actually do it.

The program can be found at https://github.com/SilviaS1/CREST-Market-for-Eve/blob/master/downloader.py
Sorry about the messy code, I'm learning by breaking up the original program.

But I'm getting the ConnectionError, I'm guessing because when it runs for a certain TypeID, it finds no record, its currently locked or something. Not sure how to diagnose it further.

I frequently get the error.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
<Greenlet at 0x93b1710: <bound method AsyncRequest.send of <grequests.AsyncRequest object at 0x0917F710>>(stream=False)> failed with ConnectionError
```

So I thought if I could write all the htmls to a csv, then do something like a pop whenever a successful return of the data, and pop the ones which error into a different csv? Instead of manually rerunning the program after every time it errors, would like it to keep on running till the end and also provide an exception list which I can then re-run?

So maybe something to catch the ConnectionError, note the TypeID or url, then keep on going? Is there a better way to solve this?